# If there's a value in the specified column, highlight row

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I already asked this question and answered it in a VBA macro.
It works ok, but what i actually want to do now is that i automate it in c# instead of making a macro, and having to fill in the specific ranges of the bad columns + values.

Currently I got this code going:

```
public void HightlightErrors()
{
     Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
     Range last = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
     Range myRange = worksheet.get_Range("A1", last);
     int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
     int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
     for (int i = 1; i < lastUsedColumn; i++) //Check each column to see if it is less than 5% filled.
     {
          Range currentColumn = worksheet.Columns[i];
          double a = application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(currentColumn);
          if ((a / lastUsedRow * 100) < 5)
          {
                //This range contains less than 5% 
                //Here i need to find the cell that has a value and highlight the Row.
          }
      }
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(last);
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myRange);
}
```

But i can't seem to find anything related to finding a value with the Range.FindNext statement. All tutorials and explanation are using a specific number or word.
I can't be that far off, anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, here is the end result

```
public void HightlightErrors()
{
     Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
     Range last = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
     Range myRange = worksheet.get_Range("A1", last);
     int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
     int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
     for (int i = 1; i < lastUsedColumn; i++) //Check each column to see if it is less than 5% filled.
     {
         Range currentColumn = worksheet.Columns[i];
         double a = application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(currentColumn);
         if ((a / lastUsedRow * 100) < 5)
         {
              string columnChar = GetExcelColumnName(i);
              string redCondition = "=COUNTA($"+ columnChar + "2)>0";
              dynamic format = myRange.FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Formula1: redCondition);
              format.Interior.Color = 0x0000FF;
         }
      }
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(last);
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myRange);
}
```

The get ExcelColumnName is this method:

```
    private string GetExcelColumnName(int columnNumber)
    {
        int dividend = columnNumber;
        string columnName = String.Empty;
        int modulo;

        while (dividend > 0)
        {
            modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
            columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
            dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
        } 
        return columnName;
    }
```